# setting default on full text search mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, full-text-search

This is my first time using full text search mysql using InnoDB. As i've read in the docs, I have the option to prepend (+) plus sign to trim the result more.

My question is can I have the default searching to automatically prepend the + when a user entered any word/s.

Eg. Say a user entered the following:

- one two => (no + sign) would result +one +two
- elliot wizard => (no + sign) would result +elliot +wizard

In the mysql it will search for the words containing the + even though the user didn't actually include the +.

PS: I searched first in the internet and did't find any article that has a solution to this..

Please help.

Regards,

Comment: I didn't understand what are you asking exactly. You can add the char + each time you receive a value

Comment: If you are talking about SQL query, better show us what do you want to achieve.

Comment: meaning i should parse the values first then add the +?

Comment: i updated my question. sorry guys

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this:

```
<?php
  $string = 'This is the string';
  $stringWithPlus = '+'.implode('+',explode(' ',$string));
  echo $stringWithPlus;
?>
```